# How to Log Boolean value from Preference

Tags: android

How to Log below value of preference? Tried all possible ways but couldn't

```
prefs.setbooleanflag(context, true);
```

Comment: do you want to put boolean value in prefrence or to get?

Comment: No, I just want to log the outcome of it

Comment: there is no such method `setbooleanflag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
 boolean vlaue = prefs.getbooleanflag(context, false);
 Log.d("tag",""+value);
```

Comment: Is this even a method?

Comment: yes its not, but i  answered to show log method .